# VueJS combine v-on click functionality

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, onclick

I was trying to combine functionality upon clicking the button in VueJS. Is it possible to run both in one click function? see below the two codes:

1. v-on click triggers function:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" @click="doingsomething">Btn1</button>
```

2. v-on click assign a value:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" @click="activeBtn = 'btn1'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn1' }">Btn1</button>
```

Comment: Try this <button class="btn" type="button" @click="doingsomething;activeBtn='btn1'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn1' }">Btn1</button>

Comment: It didn't worked on my end, I also tried ```<a class="notifIcon" @click="SideNotif, activeBtn = 'btn1'" v-bind:class="{ activeButton: activeBtn === 'btn1'}"> ``` still I can't make it work for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<button class="btn" type="button" @click="doingsomething();activeBtn='btn1'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn1' }">Btn1</button>
```

Comment: It didn't worked on my end, I also tried ```<a class="notifIcon" @click="SideNotif, activeBtn = 'btn1'" v-bind:class="{ activeButton: activeBtn === 'btn1'}"> ```

Anyways thanks for the idea. I already fixed my problem by set this to this: ```@click="SideNotif(), activeBtn ```

Here's the code:
```<a class="notifIcon" @click="SideNotif(), activeBtn = 'btn1'" v-bind:class="{ activeButton: activeBtn === 'btn1'}">```